# How to select for json mssql via knex.js?

Tags: knex.js

Is it possible to define select **for json auto** type in mssql via knex?

How to transform this:

```
select * 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
for json auto
```

into knex.js syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it properly (knex 0.21.1 and earlier):

```
const result = await knex.raw("?? for json auto", [
  knex.select()
    .from('table1 as t1')
    .leftJoin('table2 as t2', 't1.id', 't2.t1_id')
]);
```

Comment: it's generate not the same as expected: ```(select * from [table1] as [t1] left join [table2] as [t2] on [t1].[id] = [t2].[t1_id]) for json auto``` How to remove parentheses? Or how to make it as: ```(select * from [table1] as [t1] left join [table2] as [t2] on [t1].[id] = [t2].[t1_id] where [source_table].[id] = [t1].[source_id] for json path) as [data]```

Comment: Fixed. I changed `?` to `??` binding. Though I'm not sure if that is intentional feature in knex. I should check that and add tests for it. It hasn't been very clear when knex should wrap query replacement to a parenthesis and when not (I don't know why that value binding actually is wrapped).